# How to change permissions of file system in lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I am using python3.11-bullseye in dockerfile and use cdk deploy to lambda function, then us cmd 'poetry run pytest tests/' to run code test. But it can not run because the permissions of '/home':.
I also use 'chmod -R 755 /home' to access the permissons. But it can not work.
Below is the attched error message

[image]

Is there any ways to access this file system